# 正規表現 (sed や Perlなど) で複数行間の選択範囲内を置き換えたい

Tags: 正規表現, perl, sed

次のようなデータがあり、予め変数に代入されているものとします。

```
（置き換えしたいリスト以外にも任意のデータを含む場合あり）
HOGEHOGEHOGE
-果物<
りんご
ぶどう
メロン
>

\():;.'"#
?><@`ABCABC
12345

-os<
Microsoft Windows
Mac OSX
GNU/Linux
BSD
>

-timezone<
(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo
(UTC+09:00) Seoul
(UTC-07:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
(UTC+08:00) Taipei
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
>
あいうえお漢字アイウエオｱｲｳｴｵ
```

例えばここから[ **置き換え範囲として「-os<」から「>」まで** ]を指定して置き換え対象文字列として次のような文字列を変数から読み込み、指定するとします。

```
Android
iOS
Blackberry
Ubuntu Touch
```

その場合、得たい出力は次の通りです。

```
（置き換えしたいリスト以外にも任意のデータを含む場合あり）
HOGEHOGEHOGE
-果物<
りんご
ぶどう
メロン
>

\():;.'"#
?><@`ABCABC
12345

-os<
Android
iOS
Blackberry
Ubuntu Touch
>

-timezone<
(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo
(UTC+09:00) Seoul
(UTC-07:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
(UTC+08:00) Taipei
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
>
あいうえお漢字アイウエオｱｲｳｴｵ
```

尚、「timezone」や、「GNU/Linux」のように正規表現における特殊文字や「果物」のようにマルチバイト文字が置き換え前、及び、置き換え対象のいずれの変数にも含まれる可能性があるため変数内の文字列は正規表現ではなく平文の文字列として扱いたいです。

sed等で試行錯誤してみましたが特殊文字や空白をうまく処理できなかったりとどうもうまく行きません。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃたらお力をお貸しください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下ではシェルスクリプト + Perl で処理を行っています。

```sh
text=$(cat <<'EOT'
（置き換えしたいリスト以外にも任意のデータを含む場合あり）
HOGEHOGEHOGE
-果物<
りんご
ぶどう
メロン
>

\():;.'"#
?><@`ABCABC
12345

-os<
Microsoft Windows
Mac OSX
GNU/Linux
BSD
>

-timezone<
(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo
(UTC+09:00) Seoul
(UTC-07:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
(UTC+08:00) Taipei
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
>
あいうえお漢字アイウエオｱｲｳｴｵ
EOT
)

replaced=$(cat <<'EOT'
Android
iOS
Blackberry
Ubuntu Touch
EOT
)

echo "$text" | perl -0777 -pe 's/((\A|\n)-os<\n)(.|\n)+?(\n>(\Z|\n))/$1'"${replaced}"'$4/;'
```

Answer (score 0):

「正規表現 (sed や Perlなど)」ということなので, Pythonで行ってみました
もちろん, 回答ついてる perlのものとは(たぶん)別の正規表現のはずです

```py
import re
print(re.sub(r'(?<=-os<)[^>]*(?=>)', new_str, text_str, flags=re.M))

# あるいは正規表現パターンオブジェクトを利用する場合 (の文字列探索のみ)
# chg = re.compile(r'(?<=-os<)[^>]*(?=>)', re.M)
# m = chg.search(text_str)
# if m:
#   print(m[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

参考までに、(POSIX) sed で実行する場合には次です。

```
#!/bin/sh

replacement_values='Android
iOS
Blackberry
Ubuntu Touch'

escaped_for_sed_replacement=$(
    printf '%s\n' "$replacement_values" |
        sed -e '$!s/$/\\/' )

sed_script() {
    printf '
/^-os<$/,/^>$/ c\
-os<\
%s\
>' "$escaped_for_sed_replacement"
}

cat <<'EOT' | sed -e "$(sed_script)"
（置き換えしたいリスト以外にも任意のデータを含む場合あり）
HOGEHOGEHOGE
-果物<
りんご
ぶどう
メロン
>

\():;.'"#
?><@`ABCABC
12345

-os<
Microsoft Windows
Mac OSX
GNU/Linux
BSD
>

-timezone<
(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo
(UTC+09:00) Seoul
(UTC-07:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
(UTC+08:00) Taipei
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
>
あいうえお漢字アイウエオｱｲｳｴｵ
EOT
```